# Get e-mail address from Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

I have [an account](https://stackexchange.com/users/3768070/saigkill) on Stack Exchange. Is it possible to get the email address used to login?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form (with the "I lost my password" option) - this will get directly to the team.

Do note - if you do not have access to that email address (or do not recall what it was), there is likely little that can be done about it.

Frankly, if you can't prove ownership of that account, we won't simply hand you the keys.

Comment: Any reason we can't just send an email to the address associated with the account?

Comment: @ArtOfCode - sure, we can. But if the OP can't recall what email address they used... well...

Comment: @Oded Masked email address? Like s****l@g****l.com?

Comment: Yep, there's that. I was thinking more of "assuming you have X, Y, and Z accounts, and you don't know which one it was, then sending an email would identify it".

Comment: @PraveenKumar - if the OP can tell us what they think the email address is, we can confirm that and send email *to that address*.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - thing here is - the OP here could be **anyone**, we have no proof beyond their word that they own the other account. Would *you* be happy if we were to identify the email address so easily if it were your account being asked about?

Comment: The [linked profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3768070/saigkill) has [this](http://saigkill.github.io/) in the website field (*username*.github.io), and the title of that website is "Sascha Manns" - the username on this account. Not *proof* of ownership, but it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Those information is public, even I can make a fake account out of it. `:)` Oded's right.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - I too can put that github link in my profile. What does that prove?

Comment: @Oded Nothing. (The GH link is on the original profile, though, not this one.) I'm just reasoning that it's an uncommon sneaky cracker to take the title of a website orthogonally linked in a profile as a username - *possible*, yes, and certainly not proof of anything, but it makes me slightly less suspicious.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - I agree it corroborates the story, but it doesn't prove ownership. We need proof of ownership in order to restore an account... I am not accusing the OP of anything, just explaining what kinds of measures we take in order to make sure of ownership and no shenanigans. Either way, going through the "contact us" page is the best course of action for the OP. (also - I am writing my answer to help future visitors as well)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what @Oded said, you can find your method of login by going:

- Go to your [Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/348830/sascha-manns)
- Click on "Edit Profile and Settings"
- Click on "My Logins"

and the result is something like this without the blacked out part (which is personal information):

[image]

Comment: assuming he's already logged in

Comment: Given the OP posted from a different account, the assumption is that they can't access the other account, partially due to not remembering the email address used to login.